# Running a GitHub Actions step only if previous step has run

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I've set up a workflow in GitHub actions to run my tests and create an artifact of the test coverage. The stripped down version of my YAML file looks like this:

```
name: Build

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Other steps here

      - name: Build app
      - name: Run tests
      - name: Create artifact of test coverage

      # Other steps here
```

The problem is that the artifact does not get created when the tests fail.

I figured out about `if: always()` condition the from the [docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions), but this will also cause this step to run when my `Build app` step fails. I don't want that to happen because there is nothing to archive in that case.

How can I only run this step if the previous step has run (either succeeded or failed)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try checking `success()` OR `failure()`.

```
name: Build

on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Other steps here

      - name: Build app
      - name: Run tests
      - name: Create artifact of test coverage
        if: success() || failure()

      # Other steps here
```

Alternatively, create a step output of the exit code that you can check in later steps. For example:

```
      - name: Build app
        id: build
        run: |
          <build command>
          echo ::set-output name=exit_code::$?

      - name: Run tests

      - name: Create artifact of test coverage
        if: steps.build.outputs.exit_code == 0
```

Comment: For future readers, even though this is the accepted solution because there was no other option in 2020, now using Maks3w's solution is more efficient :)

Answer (score 58):

A possible better alternative is `<step>.outcome` or `<step>.conclusion`

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context

> `steps.<step id>.conclusion`. The result of a completed step after *continue-on-error* is applied. Possible values are *success*, *failure*, *cancelled*, or *skipped*. When a continue-on-error step fails, the outcome is failure, but the final conclusion is success.

> `steps.<step id>.outcome` The result of a completed step before *continue-on-error* is applied. Possible values are *success*, *failure*, *cancelled*, or *skipped*. When a continue-on-error step fails, the outcome is failure, but the final conclusion is success.

```
  - name: Build app
    id: build
    run: |
      <build command>

  - name: Run tests

  - name: Create artifact of test coverage
    if: steps.build.outcome == 'success'
```